# Page Speed Improvements - DOMContentLoaded vs First Contentful Paint

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-chrome, lighthouse

I'm looking at improving page performance and I've been using the Lighthouse plugin to suggest improvements.

One of the highest suggestions was to **Eliminate render-blocking resources**. So I moved my JavaScript includes to just above the `</body>` tag.

When I do this I see the performance rating goes up and the **First Contentful Paint** metric reduce in time.

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

But if I look at chromes Network tab and the **DOMContentLoaded** metric it actually gets slower.

**Before**
[image: Before]

**After**
[image: After]

So two questions here:

1. Which takes higher precedence in Googles eyes? The performance numbers generated by Lighthouse or DOMContentLoaded metric?
2. Why does DOMContentLoaded get slower after following Lighthouses suggestion of removing DOM blocking Javascript to the bottom?